# How to get input from user when using Floating Windows? Flag_not_focusable

Tags: java, android

I am writing a simple app (facebook messenger like chathead). i am done with the floating window but only problem is EditText inside the Floating Window is n't getting focus(can't take input) so i am not able to get input from user.
i can get the focus by changing the FLAG_LOCAL_FOCUS_MODE to window parameters.
but then i am losing the outside other system apps focus.

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

here if use WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE. apps outside of floating window are working but if i use WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LOCAL_FOCUS_MODE. only the floating window is working. i want both to work at the same time.

Comment: implement focusListener() on windowManager

Comment: Ok, thanks. but can you be more specific? do you mean to change the FLAGS every time the focus changes to windowmanger? if so, can you give a keyword or something to search the method for that?(i tried didn't find anything for window focus listener). thanks